# How can I create a workflow that automatically converts a lead in contacts?

Tags: workflow, crm, vtiger

I'm trying to create a workflow of CRM system that automatically converts Leads in Contacts and Company.

Do I have to create a custom function, or is there a built-in tool I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define custom function only. Currently there is no other way to convert lead from Workflow. Also this is not possible as we have to provide input for some mandatory fields which are in Contact or Company Module but not in Lead.